# writing "dictionary of dictionaries" to .csv file in a particular format

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am generating a dictionary out of multiple .csv files and it looks like this (example):

```
dtDict = {'AV-IM-1-13991730': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '0.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '0.92',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '0.97'},
 'AV-IM-1-13991731': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '1.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '1.92',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '1.97'},
 'AV-IM-1-13991732': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '2.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '2.92',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '2.97'},
 'AV-IM-1-13991733': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '3.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:15': '3.96',
                      '6/1/2014 0:20': '3.97'}}
```

I want to save it to a .csv file in the following format:

```
timestamp,AV-IM-1-13991730,AV-IM-1-13991731,AV-IM-1-13991732,AV-IM-1-13991733
6/1/2014 0:10,0.96,1.96,2.96,3.96
6/1/2014 0:15,0.92,1.92,2.92,3.96
6/1/2014 0:20,0.97,1.97,2.97,3.97
```

The piece of code I have as of now (related to this objective):

```
header = '''# file...... Recorder file
# date...... Thu Mar 12 14:35:32 2015
# user...... Sri
# host...... (null)
# group..... None
# property.. AVA Measurements
# limit..... 
# interval..''' 

testpower        = open("custpower.csv",'w')
testpower.writelines([header,'\n','# timestamp\n'])
...
for key, value in dtDict.iteritems():
    #Still trying to figure out how to write to custpower.csv
```

I tried doing something similar to this:

```
for key, value in dtDict.iteritems():
    testpower.writelines([key,',',','.join(value),'\n'])
```

but it didnot quite do what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is beyond simple if you can use `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'AV-IM-1-13991730': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '0.96',
                             '6/1/2014 0:15': '0.92',
                             '6/1/2014 0:20': '0.97'},
        'AV-IM-1-13991731': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '1.96',
                             '6/1/2014 0:15': '1.92',
                             '6/1/2014 0:20': '1.97'},
        'AV-IM-1-13991732': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '2.96',
                             '6/1/2014 0:15': '2.92',
                             '6/1/2014 0:20': '2.97'},
        'AV-IM-1-13991733': {'6/1/2014 0:10': '3.96',
                             '6/1/2014 0:15': '3.96',
                             '6/1/2014 0:20': '3.97'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(PATH_TO_OUTPUT_FILE)
```

`df` becomes a DataFrame that looks like

```
              AV-IM-1-13991730 AV-IM-1-13991731 AV-IM-1-13991732 AV-IM-1-13991733
6/1/2014 0:10             0.96             1.96             2.96             3.96
6/1/2014 0:15             0.92             1.92             2.92             3.96
6/1/2014 0:20             0.97             1.97             2.97             3.97
```

And your resulting csv looks like

```
,AV-IM-1-13991730,AV-IM-1-13991731,AV-IM-1-13991732,AV-IM-1-13991733
6/1/2014 0:10,0.96,1.96,2.96,3.96
6/1/2014 0:15,0.92,1.92,2.92,3.96
6/1/2014 0:20,0.97,1.97,2.97,3.97
```

Pandas is also nice because you can then do:

```
df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).plot()
# the converts change "0.97" -> 0.97 so it's plottable
```

To get:

[image: Dataframe]

Comment: This is incredibly simple. i need to read upon *DataFrame*
I will try this code on the entire file (550MB) and test it out

Comment: That is rediculously simple compared to my answer.

Comment: @Scott I tried making a list of data points like `[(timestamp, header, value) for header, d in data.items() for timestamp, value in d.items()]` and progressing from there, but I couldn't make anything work that wasn't uglier than sin. Eventually I thought "I wonder if I know pandas well enough to shift the data where it needs to go here." Turns out it all went where it was supposed to -- I lucked out!

Comment: Yeah I was trying to some clever unpacking and itertools.groupby, but couldn't come up with anything.  Nice to see pandas can do this easily.

Comment: It also looks like pandas automatically sorts or is it just a coincidence that columns and rows are sorted?

Comment: @Scott I honestly couldn't tell you. Since the original data is a dictionary, it could be that they sort that way naturally by chance, or it could be that pandas provides some sort of sorting itself. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-organize your data into a new dictionary of lists structure like this. Keep in mind, you this will read in the entire file before printing (it has to get the last value for the first timestamp). So it may be slow if your input is huge. Also, dictionaries don't keep their keys in any particular order, so if order matters you may want to save the keys in a separate list.

```
ts = dtDict.keys()

print "timestamp," + ",".join(ts)   
reformatted = {}

for k in ts:
    sub_dict = dtDict[k]
    for timestamp in sub_dict.keys():
        value = sub_dict[timestamp]
        if not reformatted.has_key(timestamp):
            reformatted[timestamp] = []
        reformatted[timestamp].append(value)

for rec in reformatted.keys():
    print rec + " " + ",".join(reformatted[rec])
```

Of course, if the set of timestamps is always consistent, you can do something even simpler:

```
datasets = dtDict.keys()
timestamps = dtDict[datasets[0]].keys()


for ts in timestamps:
    values = []
    for ds in datasets:
        values.append(dtDict[ds][ts])
    print ts + " " + "".join(values)
```

Again, it will show up in some arbitrary order unless you set the order ahead of time. So instead of setting the timestamps from the dictionary itself you would just read them in ahead of time.

Comment: timesteps and timestamps are consistent. How can I order the dictionaries with ascending time before I implement your code to write to a .csv file?

Comment: Dictionaries can't store things in order, but you can keep a separate list of the keys: 
`dtDict = {"6:15" : "0.9", "6:10" : "0.8", 6:20" : "0.2"}`
`timestamps_in_order = ["6:10", "6:15","6:20"]` 
Then, instead of looping through `data.keys()` loop through `timestamps_in_order` and reference the data by key. 

How you make the timestamp list depends on your input. You *might* be able to get away with this: 
`timestamps_in_order = dtDict[datasets[0]].keys()` `timestamps_in_order.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary of dictionaries is a bit cumbersome to navigate across your `AV-IM-1-139917XX` codes and dates.  Since we cannot guarantee the order when we call something like `dtDict.iteritems()` we need to get the keys as a list and sort them.  I do this with both the IDs (`AV-IM-1-139917XX`) and date lists.

This is what I came up with.  It may be ugly but it works:

(**edit**: added `sorted` to `dtDict.keys()`)

```
dates = []
av_im = sorted(dtDict.keys())

for k, v in dtDict.iteritems():
    dates = v.keys()  # this returns a list of date keys

dates = sorted(list(set(dates)))  # remove duplicates and sort
print dates  # ['6/1/2014 0:10', '6/1/2014 0:15', '6/1/2014 0:20']
print av_im  # ['AV-IM-1-13991730', 'AV-IM-1-13991731', 'AV-IM-1-13991732', 'AV-IM-1-13991733']
```

This gets me lists of values that I need to navigate through your dictionary.  So now I can do:

```
csv_list = []
for date in dates:
    s = str(date)
    for code in av_im:
        s = s +','+str(dtDict[code][date])
    csv_list.append(s)

print csv_list  # ['6/1/2014 0:10,0.96,1.96,2.96,3.96', '6/1/2014 0:15,0.92,1.92,2.92,3.96', '6/1/2014 0:20,0.97,1.97,2.97,3.97']
```

Now we can write to csv:

```
import csv
with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter = ',')
    w.writerows([s.split(',') for s in csv_list])
```

And we get a csv that looks like this:

```
6/1/2014 0:10,0.96,1.96,2.96,3.96
6/1/2014 0:15,0.92,1.92,2.92,3.96
6/1/2014 0:20,0.97,1.97,2.97,3.97
```

Customize as needed to include your header...

Some things to consider:  in the example you give the dates/times are simple to sort. If your real dataset spans multiple days or uses 12 hour clock or anything else more complex than what you show, then you should convert the unique list of date/time to a list of `datetime` objects and sort those.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
outStr = ''
for key, value in dtDict.iteritems():
    outStr += str(key) + ','

outStr = outStr[:-1]
print outStr

valueStr1 = '6/1/2014 0:10'
valueStr2 = '6/1/2014 0:15'
valueStr3 = '6/1/2014 0:20'

for keys, values in dtDict.iteritems():
    for key, value in values.iteritems():
        if key == '6/1/2014 0:10':
            valueStr1 += str(value)
        if key == '6/1/2014 0:15':
            valueStr2 += str(value)
        if key == '6/1/2014 0:20':
            valueStr3 += str(value)

print valueStr1
print valueStr2
print valueStr3
```

of course instead of `print` you write to your file.

EDIT: to take into account the confusion below

Comment: it is not working. The print output looks like (replaced + with ,): `AV-IM-1-13991730,AV-IM-1-13991731,AV-IM-1-13991732,AV-IM-1-13991733
('6/1/2014 0:10', '0.96')
('6/1/2014 0:20', '0.97')
('6/1/2014 0:15', '0.92')
('6/1/2014 0:10', '1.96')
('6/1/2014 0:20', '1.97')
('6/1/2014 0:15', '1.92')
('6/1/2014 0:10', '2.96')
('6/1/2014 0:20', '2.97')
('6/1/2014 0:15', '2.92')
('6/1/2014 0:10', '3.96')
('6/1/2014 0:20', '3.97')
('6/1/2014 0:15', '3.97') `

Comment: strange works fine on my computer maybe add `'\n'` escape characters when writing to file. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: what your code is doing is creating multiple instances of the time (like I pasted in the above comment) but instead the output in .csv should look like the example output I showed in the question i.e., only one timestamp should be created and the values should be appended in the same line separated by comma (as shown in my question).

Comment: not sure what you're getting at my code gives me the following output, `AV-IM-1-13991730,AV-IM-1-13991731,AV-IM-1-13991732,AV-IM-1-13991733
6/1/2014 0:100.96
6/1/2014 0:200.97
6/1/2014 0:150.92
6/1/2014 0:101.96
6/1/2014 0:201.97
6/1/2014 0:151.92
6/1/2014 0:102.96
6/1/2014 0:202.97
6/1/2014 0:152.92
6/1/2014 0:103.96
6/1/2014 0:203.97
6/1/2014 0:153.96`

Comment: it doesnt show up in this format but it is in the same format that you posted in your original post.

Comment: ahh no I take it all back :D

Comment: OK have edited so it does what I think you are asking