# Writing 3 python dictionaries to a csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 3 dictionaries( 2 of them are setdefault dicts with multiple values)-
Score_dict-

```
{'Id_1': [('100001124156327', 0.0),                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          ('100003643614411',0.0)],
 'Id_2': [('100000435456546',5.7),
          ('100000234354556',3.5)]}
```

post_dict-

```
{'Id_1':[(+,100004536)],
 'Id_2' :[(-,100035430)]}
```

comment_dict-

```
{'Id_1':[(+,1023434234)],
 'Id_2':[(-,10343534534)
          (*,1097963644)]}
```

My current approach is to write them into 3 different csv files and then merging them,I want to merge them according to a common first row(ID_row).
But I am unable to figure out how to merge 3 csv files into a single csv file. Also , Is there any way which I can write all the 3 dictionaries into a single csv without writing them individually.

Output required-

```
Ids   Score_Ids                Post_Ids      Comment_Ids
Id_1  100001124156327',0.0     +,100004536   +,1023434234
      100003643614411',0.0
Id_2  100000435456546',5.7     -,100035430   -,10343534534
      100000234354556',3.5                   *,1097963644
```

How to do this in a correct way with the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them all first, then write them to a csv file:

```
import pprint

scores = {
  'Id_1': [
    ('100001124156327', 0.0),                                            
    ('100003643614411',0.0)],
 'Id_2': [
   ('100000435456546',5.7),
  ('100000234354556',3.5)
  ]
}

post_dict = {
  'Id_1':[
    ('+',100004536)
  ],
 'Id_2' :[
    ('-',100035430)
  ]
}
comment_dict = {
  'Id_1':[
    ('+',1023434234)
  ],
  'Id_2':[
    ('-',10343534534),
    ('*',1097963644)
  ]
}

merged = {
  key: {
      "Score_Ids": value,
      "Post_Ids": post_dict[key],
      "Comment_Ids": comment_dict[key]
    }
  for key, value
  in scores.iteritems()
}

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(depth=6)

pp.pprint(merged)
```

For reference: https://repl.it/repls/SqueakySlateblueDictionaries

Comment: Okay,I am able to form a single dictionary from it, Now will writing to a csv will be same as writing any other dictionary,Also is this the best approach to do it as I am new to this and I don't have any before experience with it

Comment: I'd suggest that getting your data correct in python first, for instance by doing merging, is a preferable approach than adjusting it after in csv files. YMMV though.

Comment: Could you tell me how to write it into csv as what I am getting a dictionary of dictionary after using this.

Comment: I need it in csv

Comment: Maybe I'll just cut to the chase slightly; I'm not going to write _all_ of your code for you. You presumably already have a way of writing csv files, so all you need to do is take the data in the format it is here, and put it into the format you need

Comment: Okay, I used this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31436783/writing-dictionary-of-dictionaries-to-csv-file-in-a-particular-format but I am not getting the required format. Could you guide me correctly?

Comment: Okay, I transposed the csv file I received using the link above and got the desired result. Could you now guide me how to do it in a more correct way?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to transform your three dicts into one list of dicts before write it to a csv file.

Example

```
rows = [
    {"Score_Id": "...", "Post_Id": "...", "Comment_Id": "..."},
    {"Score_Id": "...", "Post_Id": "...", "Comment_Id": "..."},
    {"Score_Id": "...", "Post_Id": "...", "Comment_Id": "..."},
    ...
]
```

And then use the [csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class to write all the rows.

Since you have commas in your values (are you sure it's a good behaviour? Maybe splitting them in two different columns could be a better approach), be careful to use tabs or something else as separator

Comment: Yes,I am not sure what's the correct approach as I am new to this and still developing my thinking over it, any leads on how to tackle such kind of problems would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest writing all three to the same file

You could get common keys by doing something like:

```
common_keys = set(score_dict.keys()+post_dict.keys()+comment_dict.keys())
for key_ in common_keys:
    val_score = score_dict.get(key_, some_default_value)
    post_score = post_dict.get(key_, some_default_value)
    comment_score = comment_dict.get(key_, some_default_value)
    # print key and vals to csv as before
```

Comment: Okay,I got the keys ,Now how to proceed further like how to write further values in it and then to csv